# How to parse json into a dictionary<string, SoilStat> using FastJSON

Tags: c#, json, fastjson

How to convert json into a dictionary using [FastJSON](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/159450/fastJSON?msg=5061074#xx5061074xx). The string(key) is the name of the soil.

Thanks alot!

```
    "Soil": [
        {
            "name": "Pebbiland",
            "retentionrate": 1,
            "cost": 100
        },
        {
            "name": "Sandiland",
            "retentionrate": 4,
            "cost": 500
        },
        {
            "name": "Spongiland",
            "retentionrate": 8,
            "cost": 1000
        }


public class SoilStat
{
    public int retentionRate;
    public int cost;
}


Dictionary<string, SoilStat> _soilList = new Dictionary<string, SoilStat>();
```

Comment: Sorry, in the the json shown, "name" is just a member od SoilStat, not a key.  It would work (in JSON,NET anyway) as a list of SoilStat

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your JSON is incomplete.  I'm assuming you actually meant this:

```
{
    "Soil": 
    [
        {
            "name": "Pebbiland",
            "retentionrate": 1,
            "cost": 100
        },
        {
            "name": "Sandiland",
            "retentionrate": 4,
            "cost": 500
        },
        {
            "name": "Spongiland",
            "retentionrate": 8,
            "cost": 1000
        }
    ]
}
```

You can parse the above JSON in fastJSON using the following code:

```
public class Root
{
    public List<SoilStat> Soil;
}

public class SoilStat
{
    public string name;
    public int retentionRate;
    public int cost;
}

Root root = fastJSON.JSON.ToObject<Root>(jsonString);
```

If you need it as a dictionary you can convert it like this (assuming all the names are unique):

```
Dictionary<string, SoilStat> _soilList = root.Soil.ToDictionary(o => o.name);
```